# How can I set Vivaldi (browser) to use my system window decorators/borders?

Tags: window, vivaldi

How can I set [Vivaldi](https://vivaldi.com) to use my system window decorators/borders?

With Chrome/Chromium set you do this with a boolean option in the window border’s context menu. I’ve not yet found a similar setting in Vivaldi.

Comment: It would appear to be **tech preview** only at the moment (v.1.0.118.19 - Technical Preview 2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current version (Version 1.1) has a checkbox for this under `Settings -> Appearance`:

```
vivaldi://settings/appearance/
```

called `Use Native Window`:

[image]